# How to create field set according to user that wants Looping Textboxes in php

Tags: php

I've seen the other code for looping textbox, but it goesn't seem to apply in my form wizard form script.

What i need is a specific text box that loops when the user inputs a certain number of textboxes that he want to put.

**Example:**

there's a text box in which the user will enter the number of textboxes that he wanted to display, say 3. So after I click the submit button, there should be 3 textboxes as the output.

the following code when I put in form wizard not work properly

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-card">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 class="fs-title">Item Detail:</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <h2 class="steps">Step 3 - 4</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        //CODE here
    </div> <input type="button" id="next4" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Submit" onclick="validate3(0)"/>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of how you want the final HTML code to look after the person enters their "3"

Comment: refer to the above information

Comment: I am referring to the above information.  1 there is no submit button and two your answer can be achieved with a simple form post method with the number of lines requested and then a html based echo.  My request was to show an example of what you want you're proper to look like with the three text boxes as to give you a clear answer

Comment: Alex Carlson, i want to implement in my form wizard the above fieldset is the one among the 4 four steps of my form wizard and my intention to insert those textboxes in that top above steps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code sniffed to generate text boxes dynamically (using jquery).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButton").click(function () {

            if(counter>10){
                alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                return false;
            }   

            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
                '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
                '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

            counter++;
        });

        $("#removeButton").click(function () {
            if(counter==1){
                alert("No more textbox to remove");
                return false;
            }   
            counter--;

            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
        });

        $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

            var msg = '';
            for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
                msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
            }
            alert(msg);
        });

  });
</script>
</head><body>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='text' id='textbox1' >
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
```